# insert function and session into database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a query to insert but idk how to insert function and session into my database.
Thanks for helping!!

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $address   = $_POST['address'];
        $poscode   = $_POST['poscode'];
        $city      = $_POST['city'];
        $state     = $_POST['state'];
        $tel_no    = $_POST['tel_no'];
        $recipient = $_POST['recipient'];
        $date      = $_POST['date'];

        $image     = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"receipt/$image");

        $insert_order = "insert into user_order(user_email,total_payment,address,poscode,city,state,tel_no,recipient,payment_status,image,date) values ('{$_SESSION['user_email']}','".total_price()."','$address','$poscode','$city','$state','$tel_no','$recipient','pending','$image','$date')";

        $insert_order =  mysqli_query($con, $insert_order);

if($insert_order){
    echo "<script>alert('Order has been placed!')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('user/my_account.php','_self')</script>";

}}
?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all. Using prepared statements would also help you with your concatenation issues (which seems to be the actual problem).

Answer (score 2):

Please add the this line after the php tag opening.

```
session_start();
```

Without starting the session you cant use the session variables in php.

This is works in my case. Please have a try.

Comment: @beginner kk if you are trying to access the session in any page in php you should insert those line .